# TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, typeerror

I try to press the Replay button at Spotify Web Player with Python, but get this error. How can I press buttons in a webplayer?

```
replay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")[0]
replay.click()
```

Error:

```
replay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")[0]
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `find_element_by_xpath()` returns a single item, not a list.  Why are you using `[0]` on it?

Comment: Remove `[0]` since you are using `find_element_by_xpath() `

Comment: Lol thank you, it worked.

Comment: it means that the ("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""") don't return a list ... probably you are pointing to the wrong element

Answer (score 8):

This error message...

```
TypeError 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable
```

...implies that you have attached an index to a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) which is not supported.

---

### Analysis

Only *list* elements can be indexed. However, in this line of code:

```
replay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")[0]
```

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")` would always return a **single** *WebElement*. Hence you can't access the element through any index, e.g. `[0]`, `[1]`, etc as an *index* can be associated only with a *list*.

---

### Solution

There are two approaches to solve the issue.

- In the first approach, you can remove the *index*, i.e. `[0]`, and in that case `replay` will be assigned with the first matched element identified through [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

  ```
  replay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")
  ```
- In the other approach, instead of using `find_element_by_xpath()` you can create a *list* using `find_elements_by_xpath()` and access the very first element from the *List* using the index `[0]` as follows:

  ```
  replay = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")[0]
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Exception has occurred: TypeError 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63431391/exception-has-occurred-typeerror-webelement-object-is-not-subscriptable/63431470#63431470)

Answer (score 4):

For everybody, who get this error: you might have confused `driver.find_element()` with `driver.find_elements()` and you are trying to get the singular item from `WebElement` object, not from a `list` Check it in your code

`driver.find_elements()` returns a list of appropriate WebElements

There is also another function - `driver.find_element()` and you can say that:
`driver.find_element()` = `driver.find_elements()[0]`


In this example Python is trying to get the first item from `driver.find_element()` object, which returns a `WebElement` object, not a `list`

```
replay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button""")[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

returns first found element (not array)

```
find_element_by_xpath(...).click()
```

or

```
find_elements_by_xpath(...)[0].click()
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. What is the difference between the different commands?

Comment: one is plural return multiple elements the other is singular, return only one.

Answer (score 0):

As [@KunduK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10885684/kunduk) commented remove the `[0]`.

You are using absolute xPath this is not recommended.

## Try using relative xPath...

If there are a few buttons and you need the first use the `[0]` in the xpath like so:

```
replay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[0]""")
replay.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, at first I didn't understand what was going on, but it turned out to be quite simple. As it was written above find.element & find.elements work differently.
I also realized that when using find.element, 0 element is taken

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35521773)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).