# Exception has occurred: TypeError 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hello guys I'm really a **newbie** to python and I just writing a piece of code that opens ***Whatsapp***

and you give it the person's name and the message then sends how many times you want.

But when I start debugging the code it gives me this:

`Exception has occurred: TypeError 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable File "E:\Iliya\My Courses\Python\Projects\Whatsapp Robot\Whatsapp_Bot.py", line 15, in <module> msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')[1]`

```
# ======================================
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

input("Please Press The 'Enter' Button... ")
name = input("Enter Person's Name: ")
msg = input("Enter The Message: ")
counter = int(input("How Many Times Do You Want To Repeat The Message?:  "))

user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
user.click()
msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')[1]
for i in range(counter):
    msg.send_keys(msg)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1U1xa')[0]
    button.click()
```

guys please someone good at python answer me !!!

Comment: Why don't you look at what type `driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')` has?  Then you'll know why you can't index into it.  Just `print(type(driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')))` and you'll see what it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734107/typeerror-webelement-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 1):

### find_element_by_class_name()

[`find_element_by_class_name()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name) finds an element by class name.

In the line of code:

```
msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')[1]
```

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')` would return a single [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). Hence you won't be able to attach an index to it or in other words make it subscriptable.

---

### Solution

There are two solutions:

- Remove the *index* i.e. `[1]` your code will be all good.
- As an alternative, instead of `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` you need to use `find_elements_by_class_name()`. So effectively your line of code will be:

  ```
  msg = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3FRCZ')[1]
  ```

Comment: sir thanks for your answer but when I run it again it shows:  Exception has occurred: TypeError
object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
  File "E:\Iliya\My Courses\Python\Projects\Whatsapp Robot\Whatsapp_Bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    msg.send_keys(msg)

Comment: So instead of `[1]` you need `[0]` i.e. the first matched element.