# WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Not how I can't get around this error WebElement' object is not subscriptable tried everything, nothing helped

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep
        
url1 = input('[X] Введите ссылку на альбом : ')
browser.get(https://soundcloud.com/inside-edits/hamedit-posledniy-tanets-flip)
time.sleep(2)
cookies = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]")[0].click()
#cookies = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]")[0].click()
```

Before the selenium update , I did this

```
browser.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734107/typeerror-webelement-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: where are you creating object of `browser`?